# Apart from the obvious ones, what were a single free woman's job options in the U.S. in the end of the 18th Century?

Tags: economy, women

Suppose she was thirty and still single. For one reason or another her parents could no longer support her. She could be:

a governess
a seamstress
a prostitute
a laundress
a housekeeper
a cook

Suppose none of those were available, viable, or acceptable; and she could neither sing nor dance: how would she make a living?

Comment: Any number of ways.  It would probably be easier to list job options that *weren't* available.

Comment: @Mark: Name two that were, please.

Comment: Two job options that were available?  "Laundress" and "cook".

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. I actually have considered laundress. Plain cooking was part of a housekeeper's duties, though, right? ...

Comment: I think that it is not very good when your question begins looking like a Monty Python's sketch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9foi342LXQE; it is worse when it looks like two of them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tym0MObFpTI

Comment: @Alex: What you and Mark are saying is that a woman's employment options in the 18th Century were roughly the same as a man's, with the exception of a very few, very specific types of work. As much as I dislike today's version of the feminist movement, I must say couldn't agree with your view while keeping a straight face.

Comment: @Alex: Well, the reason I posted the question in the first place was to find out what those were. Instead of getting an answer or two, I got lots of derisive comments and six downvotes so far for my pains.

Comment: @Alex: Okay, dismissive, then.

Comment: @Alex: You're one of the few still apparently not privy to what I think of this site's policies.

Comment: @Alex: thank you. Ricky is spelled with a "y." Meta is spelled with one "t," and no "h."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the 18th century in the USA, the majority of the population was still engaged in farming.  All the jobs on a farm are available to women, and not uncommonly performed by women, so the statistically most likely occupation was farmworker.

The second most likely occupation is probably trades.  I will assert without proof that there were very few trades where there wasn't at least one example of a woman tradesman. While many of them were widows, (not specifically excluded by your question), some learned the trade through other means.

This question should have been closed as trivial, because if you spend 30s on google, you'll find multiple examples.  If you enter "18th century female american" and any profession, you'll come up with dozens of examples.  The following are just a quick sample I came up with in 15 minutes.  (I prudently did not ask my professional historian girlfriend, because this question would have triggered a tirade that probably would have reached through me to the internet. She has *rather strong* opinions on the historiography of women - we've accepted a myth that they were all prostitutes or helpless, waiting for rescue by a man, and that men devoted a significant fraction of their waking hours to finding new woman to oppress in new ways.  This simply isn't supported by historical facts.)

- [Tavern owner](https://www.colonialwilliamsburg.com/do/restaurants/historic-dining-taverns/christiana-campbells/) -
- [Journalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nellie_Bly)
- [Author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannah_Adams) or [Writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:18th-century_women_writers)
- [Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deborah_Sampson) or [Women in war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_women_in_war_in_the_United_States,_Pre-1945) or [solidier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Corbin) (and many more)
- [Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Blackwell)
- [Lawyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Brent)
- [Botanist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Colden)
- [Publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucretia_Mott)
- [Preacher](http://www.francisasburytriptych.com/francis-asbury-women-preachers/)
- [community organizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_Sentiments) or [reformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucretia_Mott)

If I spent more time, I'd have a longer list.